# Batch file to delete folder and its contents

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that would loop through a directory and delete any folder that is called `\SAMPLE`.

Here is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 @echo off 
 
 title WAIT !
 
 Set "sourceDir=z:\FOLDERS"
 
 IF NOT EXIST "%sourceDir%" (echo.Could not find %sourceDir% & GoTo:done)

 :: delete files 
 For /F "Delims=" %%! in ('Dir "%sourceDir%\") do (   
     rd "%%!" /s /q "%sourcedir%\ * \SAMPLE"
  )
  
 :done title,Done.......
 
 echo.&pause>nul
```

Comment: Any final _solution_ with **full source code** sample application ? _IMHO, better samples for minimize learning curve are real applications with full source code and good patterns_

Answer (score 6):

```
for /d /r Z:\Folders %d in (SAMPLE) do if exist "%d" rd /s /q "%d"
```

You'll need to use %%d in a batch file, but that's the basic form. I've used similar constructs for cleaning up Subversion working directories to remove the .svn folders.

Edit: Fixed the syntax of the for command.  I was working from memory and away from a Windows system at the time I posted.  Sorry.

Comment: thanks for the quick response but it didn't work for some reason with the following change **for /r /d %%d in (C:\Path\To\Source\*) do if exist "%%d\SAMPLE" rd /s /q "%%d\SAMPLE"**

Comment: here is the solution: `@ECHO OFF

SET FOLDER_PATH=Z:\FOLDERS
SET SUBFOLDER_NAME=SAMPLE
for /d /r %FOLDER_PATH% %%d in (%SUBFOLDER_NAME%) DO @if exist %%d echo "%%d" && rd /s/q "%%d"`

Comment: Don't forget to quote all instances of your expansion in the `for` command so you properly handle paths with spaces in them.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cadillac answer to this question. I wrote it up as a batch script which takes in option parameters and has a bit of configuration which may help OP and others who want to do slightly different things. The echo statements are optional and can be deleted if you don't want any output on the operation. Let me know if there are any bugs.

## Sample of how this might work

*This example has the wildcard option set to true, see the code below for more info*

`dir D:\deltest`

```
Wed 04/03/2013  07:05 PM    <DIR>          KEEPME
Wed 04/03/2013  07:05 PM    <DIR>          SAMPLE
Wed 04/03/2013  07:05 PM    <DIR>          SAMPLE2
```

`delete-sample-dir.bat d:\deltest`

```
Searching for *SAMPLE* in D:\deltest
Deleting the folder D:\deltest\SAMPLE
Deleting the folder D:\deltest\SAMPLE2
```

`dir D:\deltest`

```
Wed 04/03/2013  07:05 PM    <DIR>          KEEPME
```

---

## Code for `delete-sample-dir.bat`

```
    @echo off 

    REM set the name of the directory you would like to target for deleting
    set dirname=SAMPLE

    REM set the following to "true" if you want to select any directory that includes the name, e.g., a wildcard match
    set usewildcard=true


    REM --DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE---------------

    REM sentinel value for loop
    set found=false

    REM If true surround in wildcards
    if %usewildcard% == true (
        set dirname=*%dirname%*
    ) 

    REM use current working directory or take the directory path provided as the first command line parameter
    REM NOTE: do not add a trailing backslash, that is added in the for loop, so use "C:" not "C:\"
    set directorytosearch=%cd%
    if NOT "%1%" == "" (
        set directorytosearch=%1%
    )
    echo Searching for %dirname% in %directorytosearch%


    REM /r for files
    REM /d for directories
    REM /r /d for files and directories
    for /d %%i in (%directorytosearch%\%dirname%) do (
        IF EXIST %%i (
            REM change the sentinel value
            set found=true

            echo Deleting the folder %%i
            REM Delete a folder, even if not empty, and don't prompt for confirmation
            rmdir /s /q %%i
        )
    )

    REM logic to do if no files were found
    if NOT "%found%" == "true" (
        echo No directories were found with the name of %dirname%
    )
```

Comment: [Someone](http://superuser.com/questions/1159013) referenced this batch and I discovered the unquoted `%%i` vars and the imporper use of `"%1%"` instead of `"%~1"`. Aside from this the `if exist` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

@user213878 comment solution:

## Code for **deleteFolderDebug.bat**

```
@echo off
color 1F
echo.
echo Delete Debug Folder

SET FOLDER_PATH=C:\TFS\AddIn\bin
SET SUBFOLDER_NAME=Debug
SET FULLPATH=%FOLDER_PATH%\%SUBFOLDER_NAME%
IF NOT EXIST "%FULLPATH%" (echo.Could not find %FULLPATH% &GoTo:done)

echo.
echo Deleting...
for /d /r %FOLDER_PATH% %%d in (%SUBFOLDER_NAME%) DO @if exist %%d echo "%%d" && rd /s/q "%%d"

:done title,Done.......

:EOF
echo Waiting seconds
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > NUL
```